# Unable to reset/unset VERSION environment variable using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, capistrano, rails-migrations, capistrano3

I am trying to use **Capistrano** recipe to deploy a **Ruby on Rails** application to a **`CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)`** .

CentOS server has an environment variable as `VERSION` which does not allow Capistrano to run `rake db:migrate` task.

In `deploy.rb`, I created a before hook to `unset VERSION` as follows but that does not work.

```
namespace :deploy do
  before :migrating, :get_version_info 
  task :get_version_info do
    on roles(:app) do
      set :default_env, { VERSION: nil }
      execute("echo $VERSION")
      execute("unset VERSION")
      execute("echo $VERSION")
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
01:13 deploy:migrate
  [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
01:13 deploy:get_version_info
  01 echo $VERSION
  01 7
✔ 01 ssh_user@remote_server_address 0.966s
  02 unset VERSION
✔ 02 ssh_user@remote_server_address 0.960s
  01 7
✔ 01 ssh_user@remote_server_address 0.967s
01:17 deploy:migrating
  01 bundle exec rake db:migrate
  01 /opt/apps/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/net-ldap-0.5.1/lib/net/ber/core_ext.rb:38: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
  01 /opt/apps/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/net-ldap-0.5.1/lib/net/ber/core_ext.rb:45: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
  01 The PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated, and will be
  01 removed as of version 1.0.
  01
  01 You should use PG::Connection, PG::Result, and PG::Error instead, respectively.
  01
  01 Called from /opt/apps/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  01 rake aborted!
  01 ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError:
  01
  01 No migration with version number 7
  01
  01 /opt/apps/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
  01 /opt/apps/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:830:in `down'
  01 /opt/apps/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:805:in `migrate'
  01 /opt/apps/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
  01 /opt/apps/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  01 /opt/apps/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
  01 /usr/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
  01 /usr/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
  01 Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
  01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as 
ssh_user@remote_server_address: Exception while executing as 
ssh_user@remote_server_address: rake exit status: 1
```

Any help or workaround would be highly appreciated.

> **Tools Info**
>
> Capistrano Version: 3.10.2 (Rake Version: 12.3.1)
>
> ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053)
>
> Rails 4.2.8

Answer (score 0):

These are my findings and solution to overcome this problem:

***Findings:***

1. **CentOS** does not have a `VERSION` environment variable by default.
2. In my case, `VERSION` env variable was being set by the private cloud infrastructure with a file in `/etc/profile.d/` path.
3. From Capistrano [guide](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/):

   > By default Capistrano always assigns a non-login, non-interactive shell.

***Solutions:***

1. In my case I was sure that if I `unset VERSION` then it won't impact my environment. So, I added `unset VERSION` to my `~/.bashrc`. It worked for me!

   Note: if you unset VERSION in `~/bash_profile`, then it wont work due to the non-interactive, non-login nature of Capistrano by default.
2. Another workaround could be to use [Capistrano command_map](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#the-command-map)  to execute `bundle exec rake db:migrate` task.